# Prototype object

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm not entirely too familiar with prototypes, and I'm sure this is the incorrect implementation but I've put together a tiny example of what I'm trying to achieve.

I could make the prototype a literal object instead of a function but than I ran into issues where I cannot access the variables/properties inside the Object I'm creating a prototype of (in this case Person).

```
Person = function() {
  this.name = 'mike';
  this.departureSaying = 'Adios amigo!';
}

Person.prototype.say = function() {
  var self = this;
  function hello() { alert('hello my name is ' + self.name); }
  function goodbye() { alert(self.departureSaying); }
}

var mike = new Person();
mike.say.hello();
mike.say.goodbye();
```

If you run this you'll get Object has no method hello and goodbye.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your two functions are local to the method; you're not returning them.

```
Person.prototype.say = function() {
    var self = this;

    return {
        hello: function() { alert('hello my name is ' + self.name); },
        goodbye: function() { alert(self.departureSaying); }
    };
};
```

And then you'll want:

```
mike.say().hello();
mike.say().goodbye();
```

However, I don't believe using the prototype is right for this situation. Assign it in the constructor, instead:

```
function Person() {
    var self = this;

    this.name = 'mike';
    this.departureSaying = 'Adios amigo!';

    this.say = {
        hello: function() { alert('hello my name is ' + self.name); },
        goodbye: function() { alert(self.departureSaying); }
    };
}
```

[Here's a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/TGSTL/)